# Is it possible to calculate accuracy and ROC-AUC score at the same time with GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cross-validation, grid-search

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
parameters = {'bootstrap': [True, False], 'min_samples_split':[2,3,4], 
'criterion':['entropy', 'gini'], 'n_estimators':[100, 200]             }
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf, param_grid=parameters, 
scoring='accuracy', cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
```

My code currently performs a grid search with `GridSearchCV`, scoring predictions by their accuracy. How can I calculate the ROC-AUC score as well without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), you can pass a `list` of strings. In this specific case, `scoring=['accuracy', 'roc_auc']` would be what you want.